# Swift: Calling a function with parameters that may be nil

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to figure out if there is any shorter syntax in Swift for the last line here:

```
var startPosition: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
var latitude: Double?
var longitude: Double?
// ...
// Here I have skipped some code which may or may not assign values
// to "latitude" and "longitude".
// ...
if latitude != nil && longitude != nil {
    startPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude!, longitude!)
}
```

As you can see, I want to set the "startPosition" based on "latitude" and "longitude", if those values have been assigned. Otherwise, I accept that the "startPosition" will not be initialized.

I guess this must be possible with "if let" or something similar, but I have failed to figure out how. (I'm experienced in Objective-C, but have just started to learn Swift.)

Answer (score 6):

This is not shorter, but you can simply do

```
if let latitude = latitude, let longitude = longitude {
     startPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude,
                                        longitude: longitude)
}
```

Notice I used just CLLocationCoordinate2D, not CLLocationCoordinate2DMake.  Swift provides constructors without the "make" to most common objects, so you shouldn't usually have to use "make" in constructors.

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer! Let's see if someone else will find a shorter syntax for doing this. In any case, your answer helped me to understand "if let" better.

Comment: You shouldn't have replaced `CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)` with `CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude, longitude)` in your answer, because the latter form doesn't compile. If using the struct initializer, one must include the full argument labels as in the answer by Edward Anthony : `CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)`.

Comment: Yes good point, sorry moving to quickly.  Edward *is* correct though, you should use the struct initializer here.  As you learn swift you will find that you will have interpolated ObjectiveC *and* corresponding Swift methods at your disposal.  Its up to you to pick the Swift methods.

Comment: @Magnus if this is a 'shorter answer' race. Use `lat` and `lng` instead :D

Comment: What are the benefits of using the struct initializer compared to using the good old "make" function? Is it about beauty and keeping the language clean? Or are there any more substantial benefits? Just curious...

Comment: Functionally they are exactly the same.  Performance wise, I am not sure, but they probably compile to be the same as well.  From a code maintanence perspective though, the struct initializer is a newer API designed specifically for Swift, so perhaps the older Objective C api is more likely to be deprecated.  I hate the phrase *best practice* but it seems appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to execute any code after if they are nil use a guard.

```swift
var startPosition: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
var latitude: Double?
var longitude: Double?

guard let latitude = latitude && longitude = longitude else {
    return
}

startPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
```

Answer (score 1):

Clear way

```
if let latitude = latitude, longitude = longitude {
     startPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude,
                                            longitude: longitude)
}
```

CLLocationCoordinate2D is a struct, it's better if you use the struct initializer. Notice there is only one "let" needed in the if statement.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If i understood the question correctly, you could say

```html
var startPosition: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
var latitude: Double?
var longitude: Double?

if latitude != nil && longitude != nil {
startPosition = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude!, longitude!)
} else {
startPosition = nil
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but that gives the same result as my own code. Perhaps I should have stated clearer that "startPosition" is uninitialized (i.e. equals nil) when executing the if statement.